# Lazy load is not working on .svg and .png image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, lazy-loading

**I am try to applying lazy load on images but it only works for .jpg extension.  Lazy load is not working for .png and .svg extension. Is there any other method for that?**

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code. There are several methods for lazy load, so we don't have to guess which one doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here:

```css
html,
body,
div
{
  height: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div>scroll down for PNG</div>

<img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googleg/2x/googleg_standard_color_64dp.png" alt="..." loading="lazy" onload="alert('png loaded');">

<div>scroll down for SVG</div>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Trajans-Column-lower-animated.svg" alt="..." loading="lazy" onload="alert('svg loaded');">
```